# Create a dictionary from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary from a csv file. CSV would look something like this:

```
hostnames,device_platform,device_role
co-agg-r1,cisco_ios,co-agg-r
co-edg-fw,cisco_asa,co-edg-fw
co-acc-sw,cisco_ios,co-acc-sw
co-acc-rsw,broadcom_icos,co-acc-rsw
```

I need the dictionary to be created so that the hostnames are the keys. Something like this:

```py
devices_dict = {
 'co-agg-r1': { 'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-agg-r'},
 'co-edg-fw': { 'device_platform': 'cisco_asa', 'device_role': 'co-edg-fw'},
 'co-acc-sw1': { 'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-acc-sw'},
 'co-acc-rsw1': { 'device_platform': 'broadcom_icos', 'device_role': 'co-acc-rsw'}
}
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: pandas: `pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0).to_dict('index')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative without Pandas (nothing wrong with Pandas):

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    keys = next(reader)[1:]
    devices_dict = {key: dict(zip(keys, values)) for key, *values in reader}
```

Result:

```
{'co-agg-r1': {'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-agg-r'},
 'co-edg-fw': {'device_platform': 'cisco_asa', 'device_role': 'co-edg-fw'},
 'co-acc-sw': {'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-acc-sw'},
 'co-acc-rsw': {'device_platform': 'broadcom_icos', 'device_role': 'co-acc-rsw'}}
```

Comment: I like the Pandas option, however, this answer works best for my use case. I plan to share this script with a team, and want as little user interaction as possible, including having to install the Pandas package in order to run the script. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/data.csv")  # data you provided
df.set_index("hostnames").T.to_dict()  # or df.set_index("hostnames").to_dict("index")
```

yields

```
{'co-agg-r1': {'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-agg-r'},
 'co-edg-fw': {'device_platform': 'cisco_asa', 'device_role': 'co-edg-fw'},
 'co-acc-sw': {'device_platform': 'cisco_ios', 'device_role': 'co-acc-sw'},
 'co-acc-rsw': {'device_platform': 'broadcom_icos',
  'device_role': 'co-acc-rsw'}}
```